# Need help refactoring this basic async-await loop

Tags: c#, async-await

So I have a business object that supports a "Save"-method which does some IO to some device. I then have a list of those objects which I want to save asynchronously in a batch. My code now looks like this:

```
    public async Task Save()
    {
        foreach (var element in Elements)
        {
            await element.Save();
        }
    }
```

Now this results in `n` number of awaits, and I know that each await causes a bit of CPU overhead. I want to eliminate this and only have one single await. How do I refactor to achieve this?

Comment: If `Save()` does I/O, would the CPU overhead really matter?

Comment: Can you put the foreach in a different method then call that after the await?

Comment: Can the next element only be saved if the previous is already saved?

Comment: @millimoose In my case it may because I do dirty-checking in the Save-method. If the object is not dirty, no I/O is done - hence the dominating CPU-time for those calls will be the async/await-padding. If I have a list of 10000 objects, and only 1 is dirty, I will end up with 9999 unnecessary async-awaits, which I suspect will be significant.

Comment: @marvc1 Good question. Both scenarios could be relevant, but primarily I'd like to do them serially ("Yes").

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you could call `Save()` on everything and then await all of them finishing using [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public async Task Save()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(Elements.Select(x => x.Save());
}
```

or if you really don't do anything else, just:

```
public Task Save()
{
    return Task.WhenAll(Elements.Select(x => x.Save());
}
```

EDIT: If you want to do them serially, use the code you've already got. It's worth noting that the way async/await has been designed, awaiting a call which *actually* completes synchronously (e.g. a cache hit, or in your case dirty checking) is really cheap. It doesn't need to do any task scheduling, create a continuation or anything like that. You say:

> If I have a list of 10000 objects, and only 1 is dirty, I will end up with 9999 unnecessary async-awaits, which I suspect will be significant.

As ever, *suspicions* about performance bottlenecks are pretty much meaningless - what's important is *evidence* about performance bottlenecks. Have you tried the existing code and *measured* the cost? If not, I strongly suggest you do that before changing anything.

Comment: Technically that answers my questions since I didn't initially specify that I'd like to do them serially. Do you have a solution to the same problem if order of the save calls matters?

Comment: @Nilzor: If you want to do them serially, that sounds impossible to me  with the given API. After all, without awaiting the first result, how are you going to know when to start the next call? Will update with a comment based on your question comments though.

Comment: Just curious, after switching to using Task.WhenAll, why keep Save() as async and use await on the WhenAll instead of just returning the WhenAll task?  Is there a benefit to one vs. the other?

Comment: @JamesManning: Not particularly - it's something I always forget as an option. Will edit to make that clearer.